# How to read starting N words from each rows in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading excel which has free text in a column.Now after reading that file from pandas, I want to restrict the column having text to read just N words from starting for each rows. I tried everything but was not able to make it.

data["text"] = I am going to school and I bought something from market.

But I just want to read staring 5 words. so that it could look like below.

data["text"] = I am going to school.

and I want this same operation to be done bow each row for data["text"] column.

You help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. but I am getting this error while trying what you suggested.AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @desertnaut:will take care of it next time

Answer (score 2):

```
def first_k(s: str, k=5) -> str:
    s = str(s)  # just in case something like NaN tries to sneak in there
    first_words = s.split()[:k]
    return ' '.join(first_words)
```

Then, apply the function:

```
data['text'] = data['text'].apply(first_k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data["text"] = [' '.join(s.split(' ')[:5]) for s in data["text"].values]
```

Comment: Hi! While this may provide an answer, it is generally discouraged on StackOverflow to leave code only answers. Please explain why this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors. Thanks!